# Filter view from $_GET parameters

Tags: views

I have a classic view with fields from classic nodes. I have made a custom form that reload the view with parameters :

```
mypage?nid=168
```

But to display only the wanted data, my view use **CONTEXTUAL FILTERS** and need this format :

```
mypage/168
```

How can I filter my view from **$_GET** parameters.

Comment: what do you mean by classic? Does the form reload something with ajax or simply post to the view. What arguments are you passing to the view from the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can achive it by using **[views php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php)** module.

- Add contextual filter

  [image]
- Select the field using which you want to filter. I'm using **Content NID** as filter parameter

  [image]
- Add the PHP code for filtering

  [image]
- PHP code

  ```
   
  if(isset($_GET['nid']))
      return $_GET['nid'];
  else
      return;
  ```
- Just add the param in the URL

  [image]

Note :

- check the permission of views_php module
- Make the changes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Use "**Global: PHP**" field to get the required parameter value. If **views_php** is not installed, then use this link, [**views_php**](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) to install the module and give the permission using **admin/people/permissions**.

Go to your Views -> CONTEXTUAL FILTERS -> ADD -> Select "Global: PHP" then you can retrieve the parameter using **$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]** and retrieve the value.

And also you can use **$_GET['nid']** to get the value.